# Install Python packages first from private registry, if package not found from pypi

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install packages with pip from a with Poetry generated requirements.txt which contains packages from PyPi.org and from a private GitLab package registry. The packages should be first looked up in the private registry. If not existing there, they should be grabbed from PyPi.org.

I've tried to install them with:

```
python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir \
            --index-url https://gitlab.domain.tld/api/v4/groups/18/-/packages/pypi/simple/ \
            --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ \
            --trusted-host gitlab.domain.tld \
            --disable-pip-version-check \
            --verbose \
            -r requirements.txt
```

I've also created a .netrc:

```
machine gitlab.domain.tld login <username> password <password>
```

This is the beginning of requirements.txt generated by `poetry export | tee requirements.txt`:

```
--index-url https://gitlab.domain.tld/api/v4/groups/18/-/packages/pypi/simple

certifi==2022.12.7 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0" \
    --hash=sha256:35824b4c3a97115964b408844d64aa14db1cc518f6562e8d7261699d1350a9e3 \
    --hash=sha256:4ad3232f5e926d6718ec31cfc1fcadfde020920e278684144551c91769c7bc18
.
.
.
```

This fails with:

```
#0 0.786 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi==2022.12.7 (from versions: none)
#0 0.786 ERROR: No matching distribution found for certifi==2022.12.7
```

If I'm trying to remove the first --index-url line in requirements.txt because the index and extra index are defined in the pip parameters, all the packages from PyPi.org are installing, but failing at the first package from private repository:

```
#0 1.415 Collecting click==8.1.3
#0 1.437   Downloading click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
#0 1.448      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 96.6/96.6 KB 10.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 1.680 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement my-package==0.4.0 (from versions: none)
#0 1.681 ERROR: No matching distribution found for my-package==0.4.0
```

Allthough pip is somehow accessing private repository, because it's failing if I put a mistake in e.g. the password.

Comment: We have our pypi server to do the automatic fail to route to pypi, I will try and find out what settings we used to do this

Comment: You can try setting `pip.conf` with the correct index-url (internal server) and then set `extra-index-url` to use the global pypi.